# Is it possible to change the target document of the object created by window.URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, blob

I understand that the lifetime of the object created by `window.URL.createObjectURL` is tied to the document. Is there any way I can change the target document ?
 I am developing a chrome extension and the problem I am facing is that the `DOMString` objects created lose their ties to my Blob files as soon as a user refreshes the page. I want to maintain my Blob files URLs outside the scope of the document. Perhaps there is a way I can move them over to my background script?

Comment: I don't quite get you. Did you mean you want to keep the video URL after the blob object being created so that when the website reloads, the video tag still have the blog URL?

Comment: I already got a blob file, but I still need to maintain a url created by window.URL.createObjectURL outside the scope of the document.

Comment: move the blob, not its URL representation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can change the target document ?

You can use the structured clone algorithm to pass the blob object itself to a different document or a worker. Installing a service worker can have a lifetime longer than a document, which should allow you to pass forward blobs from one document to a future document.

The blob URI cannot be passed because the blob url store [gets cleaned on document unload](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#BlobURLStore).

You can also use [indexddb to store blobs](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/)